# Evaluate Razor variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to evaluate a razor variable inside a JavaScript function. Given the following code:

```
 @{var unseenNotificationsExist = false;}
 
 @foreach(var notification in viewModel)
 {
    if (notification.WasSeen == false)
    {
      unseenNotificationsExist = true;
      break;
    }
 }
```

I need to evaluate the `unseenNotificationsExist` variable in JavaScript like this:

```
 if(@unseenNotificationsExist == true)
        $('#unseenNotifCount').addClass('notifNotSeen');
```

However, when I debug the JavaScript code, I get this:

```
if(True == true)
```

and also I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError True is not defined

Answer (score 5):

```
var unseenNotificationsExist = @(unseenNotificationsExist?"true":"false") ;
//the line above must be part of your view

if(unseenNotificationsExist === true)
        $('#unseenNotifCount').addClass('notifNotSeen');
//this can be part of your js file or alternatively and less 
//preferably part of your view
```

Comment: It also works including all the code in the javascript snippet in the view

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround: I added this

```
var True = true
```

Now, in javascript there is a variable "True" defined and the evaluation comes down to True == true, which returns true.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use **Json.Encode** , whenever i want to convert the model data to JSON objects or JSON variables .

**For converting an object(dto) of model to javascript**

```
var accountDto = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.AccountDto))
```

**For converting a (bool)property of model**

```
var isTrue = @Json.Encode(Model.IsTrue)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not have the the JavaScript rendered, use Daniele's suggestion.

If you insist on making the comparison in JavaScript:

```
if(@unseenNotificationsExist.ToString().ToLower() === true)
```

Comment: Though this might work but it will be a good practice to change the varible into javascript our self and then manipulate it. Just depending upon ToString() wont be a good option

Comment: also this type of patten wont allow the user to separate all the js code in a separate file

Comment: It's not a pretty solution, agreed! But your solution will not allow a separate JS file either... ;-)
EDIT: In fact, I take that back - you were certainly only referring to the `if` part.

Comment: why not.. i just making a global variable.. and i have edited my ans please check again

Comment: Yeah I see that now, it wasn't there when I posted, but I figured that out eventually.

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
if('@unseenNotificationsExist')
```

Comment: My answer was incomplete, I edited it. This seems to work for me.

Comment: this will always go into true block because in js dosent matter you check if("True") or if("False")

Comment: correct. you could not initialize the variable with false though, just declare it.

Answer (score -1):

You tried with:

```
if('@unseenNotificationsExist' === 'True')
        $('#unseenNotifCount').addClass('notifNotSeen');
```

Comment: it still will remain True and not true

Comment: Yes, I did, same result.

Comment: It's only missing an `@` in front of the `if` imo, possibly curly braces too to make it a *C#-if*.

Comment: the if is in javascript not razor